# How to close a dialog in Flutter using the Back button on Android?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget that I use for alerts. With the help of this widget I display alerts. I ran into a problem, I need to use the Back button that is in the Android system (at the bottom of the screen) to close my dialog box. Now when I click, nothing happens and the dialog does not close. How to close an alert using the Back button on Android?

```
Future<dynamic> showFlexibleBorderDialog({
    required BuildContext context,
    required Widget child,
    Function()? onPositivePressed,
    Function()? onNegativePressed,
    Color borderColor = constants.Colors.purpleMain,
    EdgeInsets margin = const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
    EdgeInsets padding =
        const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18, vertical: 34),
    bool barrierDismissible = true,
  }) async {
    dynamic isSelected;
    return await showDialog(
        context: context,
        useRootNavigator: false,
        barrierDismissible: barrierDismissible,
        builder: (context) {
          return FlexibleBorderDialog(
            borderColor: borderColor,
            margin: margin,
            padding: padding,
            child: child,
          );
```

**body**

```
ShowCustomDialog().showFlexibleBorderDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: false,
      child: PoyntLocationDialog()),
```

Comment: ``barrierDismissible: true,``

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the alert dialog with `WillPopScope()`?

```
ShowCustomDialog().showFlexibleBorderDialog(
  barrierDismissible: false,
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope( //<---
      child: PoyntLocationDialo(
        ................
      ),
      onWillPop: (){return true},
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Yes, it didn't work.